# "Beyond help" or "beyond helpless"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences, semantics

*Beyond help* is an expression meaning "beyond the help of anything" or "not able to be fixed". However, I have also seen the expression *beyond helpless* being used, for example, [here](https://jaymarcy.livejournal.com/676320.html) and [here](https://twitter.com/DHick95/status/321104513257844737). My questions are:

1. Is *beyond helpless* semantically correct, and
2. In what ways is it different from *beyond help*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Beyond help* means that any attempt to help will be futile: nothing that can be done will make the situation any better.

> John is **beyond help**: he insists on doing things his own way, and ignores our advice.
>   Kathy has gone too far this time. She's **beyond help**, and will have to find her own way through this.

*Helpless* is an odd word; it doesn't mean "lacking help"<sup>†</sup> but is used today mostly in the sense of being incapable of acting on one's own behalf. *Beyond helpless* represents a common colloquial use of *beyond* to mean *transcending*: a person who is *beyond helpless* is so helpless, so incapable of action, that the word *helpless* is inadequate:

> Sara's pretty helpless, she can't write the simplest email without making spelling mistakes or sending it to the wrong person. But Mike's **beyond helpless**: he can't even turn the computer on.

---

<sup>†</sup>The word arose at a time when *help* was used more often than it is today to designate *resources* or *means* of doing something.